# Pasar nombres compuetos a simples mediante Regex en C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, regex, asp.net-core

Soy nuevo en el tema de expresiones regulares y me gustaría saber como conseguir pasar los nombres compuestos a simples. Pongo un ejemplo:

```
RUIZ JIMENO, ALBERTO ADRIAN => RUIZJIMENOALBERTO
LÓPEZ FAUSTO,   CATALINA DE MIGUEL => LOPEZFAUSTOCATALINA
```

Estoy en C#, concretamente en Asp.net-core. Lo que he probado por el momento es (se que está mal):

```
Regex.Replace("RUIZ JIMENO, ALBERTO ADRIAN", "[\w\s\w,\s\w]", "")
```

Quisiera investigar mas sobre esto pero estoy en el trabajo y no puedo perder mucho tiempo.

Un saludo, muchas gracias!

P.D: Algo que estuve viendo ayer sobre expresiones regulares (pnho link):

https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/2015/01/29/regexsam/

Comment: Cuáles son las relgas para juntar los nombres? Unir los dos apellidos y el primero de los nombres (descartando el segundo nombre si lo hubiera)? Es así?

Comment: Quisiera ayudarte pero estoy en el trabajo y no puedo perder mucho tiempo.

Comment: Correcto Julio. Descartar todo aquello que vaya despues de uno o varios espacios en blanco del primer nombre.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con lo siguiente:

Buscar:

```
^(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s*,\s*(\w+).*
```

Remplazar por:

```
$1$2$3
```

Tienes una demo [aquí](https://regex101.com/r/5vaYrQ/1/).

Y un ejemplo de código aquí.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace("RUIZ JIMENO, ALBERTO ADRIAN", @"^(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s*,\s*(\w+).*", @"$1$2$3"));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Con expresiones regulares no te sabría decir, pero con manipulación de arrays por ejemplo podría ser algo así:

```
public string aSimple (string nombreEnCuestion)
{
    string[] comaSplit = nombreEnCuestion.Split(',');
    string[] names = comaSplit[1].Split(' ');
    return String.Format("{0}{1}", comaSplit[0].Replace(" ", String.Empty), Array.Find(names, isNotNull));
}

public bool isNotNull (string s)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Ahora pruebo.